# Log-linearization in RBC model

Tags: rbc, log-linearization

Can anyone show how by applying log-linearization we can turn this equation:

$\frac{X_t}{C_t} = \left( (1 - \vartheta) + \vartheta \left( \frac{L_t}{C_t} \right)^{1-\nu} \right)^\frac{1}{1-\nu}$

into this one:

$x_t - c_t = \frac{1}{1 - \nu} \frac{\vartheta \left( \frac{L}{C}\right)^{1-\nu} }{(1 - \vartheta) + \vartheta \left( \frac{L}{C}\right)^{1-\nu} } (1-\nu) (l_t - c_t)$

where values without the subscript $t$ denote steady state values and values in smaller case denote log values.

Comment: Source for the equation?

Comment: Monetary policy, inflation and the business cycle (Gali, 2008), pg. 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the natural logarithm, rewrite

$$ x_t - c_t = \frac{1}{1 - v}\ln\left[ 1 - \theta + \theta e^{(1-v)(l_t - c_t)}\right]$$

Notice that I'm doing nothing, since $e^{(1-v)(l_t - c_t)}= (L_t/C_t)^{1-v}$

Substitute $ y_t = l_t - c_t$ and take a First Order Taylor Expansion around $l - c = 0$ (differentiate w.r.t. $y$), and notice that you can rewrite $1 = L/C$ and you get the expression.

P.S. Are you sure that the last $l_t - c_t$ is not a log deviation? In theory, you linearize around the steady state!

Comment: This is from Monetary policy, inflation and the business cycle (Gali, 2008), pg. 29. the book says it's doing a log linearization around a zero inflation steady state, but it also clearly states that x_t = ln(X_t)

Comment: Ok, but what is $L_t$ and what is $C_t$, then? Initially, I thought consumption and leisure, but here? Liquidity and consumption?

Comment: Consumption and leisure